# Problem in putting Linked List node into the Python Priority Queue

Tags: python, linked-list, priority-queue

I'm basically trying to put Linked list nodes into a priority queue. Here **ListNode** is my LinkedList class and **lists** is a python list that contains heads of different linked lists. I've no idea why I'm getting the following error message.

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ListNode' and 'ListNode'

```
  Q = PriorityQueue()
for node in lists:
    if node:
        Q.put((node.val,node))
```

LinkedList class:

```
class ListNode:
def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
    self.val = val
    self.next = next
```

Answer (score 1):

oh, I finally get it. It's because of the same priority actually. Whenever there are two values with the same priority, Priority queue tries to compare the **ListNode** object and raise this error. An easy solution is to use a **counter** variable.

```
Q = PriorityQueue()
count = 0
for node in lists:
   if node:
       Q.put((node.val, count, node))
       count += 1
```